Excel cell text line break

My goal is to make line break after ever name, surnam, which is divided by comma. If i don't do that the cell is too small and text is not fully visible. Since its the macro created form, each time the length of people names varies, therefore to set bigger cell area (currently several merged cells) is not a solution. So far i tried few options, and non of them works.
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("E11:N13")
    With rng
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With

    Rows("13:13").RowHeight = 68

    Range("E8:G8").Merge
    Range("E8").FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"

    If Not IsEmpty(rng.Value) And VarType(rng.Value) = vbString Then
        If InStr(rng.Value, ",") > 0 Then
'            rng.Value = Replace(rng.Value, ",", vbNewLine)
'rng.Value = Replace(rng.Value, ",", Chr(10))
rng.Value = Replace(rng.Value, ",", vbLf)

        End If
    End If


Please provide some sample data and your expected output - then it is easier to help

rng.Value places the range in an array and you cannot apply VBA.Replace to an array. It works only on strings and you need iteration.  But you should use Range.Replace. You should simple use  rng.Replace ",", vbLf.

Please, use the next adapted code:
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("E11:N13")
    With rng
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .Replace ",", vbLf
    End With

VBA.Replace does not work on arrays and rng.Value places the range in an array.
